# How to bring the relationships of a certain model to display them in a table with Inertia::render?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui, inertiajs

I'm trying to get the relationships for a model from the controller so be able to display the relationship not as a id but as that id's name or type or whatever it might be. In this case I'm trying to get information relating to a question, what response type it has (text, multiple, rank, yes or no) and also which section is belongs to (the name)

This is my controller code so far

```
public function index()
{
    return Inertia::render('Question/Index', [
        'survey_question' => SurveyQuestion::all(),
        'survey_section' => SurveySection::all(),
        'response_type' => ResponseType::all()
    ]);
}
```

The table in the vue

```html
<el-table
    :data="tableData">
    <el-table-column
        prop="question"
        label="Pregunta">
    </el-table-column>
    
    <el-table-column
        label="Seccion">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <p> {{ scope.row.survey_section.title }} </p>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
    
    <el-table-column
        label="Tipo de Respuesta">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <p> {{ scope.row.response_type.type }} </p>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
    
    <el-table-column
        prop="optional"
        label="Opcional">
    </el-table-column>

    <el-table-column>
        <template slot-scope="scope">
                <div class="btn-link-edit action-button" @click="edit(scope.row)">
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="delete(scope.row)">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </div>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

This brings the relationships I think, because when I create a new question I have a select option and it does show the names instead of the ids, but when I'm trying to display said name in a table I can only access the id.

I also would like to know how to show for the optional field instead of 0 or 1, yes or no. This field is a boolean in the table structure if that is important.

If I do `{{ scope.row }}` then I get the information but only of the question like this

```
{ "id": 1, "question": "asdfasdf", "survey_section_id": 1, "response_type_id": 1, "optional": 1 }
```

What I would like is that when I do `{{ scope.row }}` I also get from those ids another array with the information related to that id both from the section and the response type.

Comment: It is not apparent as how you're transforming the data, and thus very hard to help you with this. What is the `scope` variable in this case? Are you iterating over the `survey_question` prop in your example? 
Please include the complete files of the files that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `with` method in the eloquent model. For example:

```
$result = Model::with(['nameOfTheRelationShip'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Josias says, you should use `with` method.

The best practice in laravel is to return the eloquent data then call it in `defineProps` to use with vue/inertia

Lets say you have a model for `devices` that belongs to `clients`, and you want to index all the devices with the `client.name`.
In your `devices` controller you would return all the devices with the client relationship as follows

```php
public function index()
{
    $devices = Device::with(['client'])->get();
    return Inertia::render('Devices/Index', compact(['devices']));
}
```

Then in the vue Devices/Index you just have to declare the `devices` in the `definedProps` like

```js
defineProps(['devices']);
```

then you can make a simple `v-for` statement

```js
<script setup>
    import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
    import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";
     
    defineProps(['devices']);
</script>
 
<template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>
                    Client
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Model
                </th>
                <th>
                    Year
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="device in devices" :key="index">
                    <td>
                        {{ device.client.name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ device.name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ device.model }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ device.year }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```